# JavaScript - Efficiently find all elements containing one of a large set of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a set of strings and I need to find all all of the occurrences in an HTML document. Where the string occurs is important because I need to handle each case differently:

- String is all or part of an attribute. e.g., the string is foo: `<input value="foo">` -> Add class ATTR to the element.
- String is the full text of an element. e.g., `<button>foo</button>` -> Add class TEXT to the element.
- String is inline in the text of an element. e.g., `<p>I love foo</p>` -> Wrap the text in a span tag with class TEXT.

Also, I need to match the longest string first. e.g., if I have foo and foobar, then `<p>I love foobar</p>` should become `<p>I love <span class="TEXT">foobar</span></p>`, not `<p>I love <span class="TEXT">foo</span>bar</p>`.

The inline text is easy enough: Sort the strings descending by length and find and replace each in `document.body.innerHTML` with `<span class="TEXT">$1</span>`, although I'm not sure if that is the most efficient way to go.

For the attributes, I can do something like this:

```
sortedStrings.each(function(it) {
     document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('(\S+?)="[^"]*'+escapeRegExChars(it)+'[^"]*"','g'),function(s,attr) {
        $('[+attr+'*='+it+']').addClass('ATTR');
     });
});
```

Again, that seems inefficient.

Lastly, for the full text elements, a depth first search of the document that compares the `innerHTML` to each string will work, but for a large number of strings, it seems very inefficient.

Any answer that offers performance improvements gets an upvote :)

EDIT: I went with a modification on Bob's answer. `delim` is an optional delimiter around the string (to differentiate it from normal text), and `keys` is the list of strings.

```
function dfs(iterator,scope) {
    scope = scope || document.body;
    $(scope).children().each(function() {
        return dfs(iterator,this);
    });
    return iterator.call(scope);
}

var escapeChars = /['\/.*+?|()[\]{}\\]/g;
function safe(text) { 
    return text.replace(escapeChars, '\\$1');
}

function eachKey(iterator) {
    var key, lit, i, len, exp;
    for(i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
        key = keys[i].trim();
        lit = (delim + key + delim);
        exp = new RegExp(delim + '(' + safe(key) + ')' + delim,'g');            
        iterator(key,lit,exp);
    }
}

$(function() {
    keys = keys.sort(function(a,b) {
        return b.length - a.length;
    });

    dfs(function() {
        var a, attr, html, val, el = $(this);
        eachKey(function(key,lit,exp) {
            // check attributes
            for(a in el[0].attributes) {
                attr = el[0].attributes[a].nodeName;
                val = el.attr(attr);
                if(exp.test(val)) {
                    el.addClass(attrClass);
                    el.attr(attr,val.replace(exp,"$1"));
                }
            }
            // check all content
            html = el.html().trim();
            if(html === lit) {
                el.addClass(theClass);
                el.html(key); // remove delims
            } else if(exp.test(html)) {
                // check partial content
                el.html(html.replace(exp,wrapper));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Under the assumption that the traversal is the most expensive operation, this seems optimal, although improvements are still welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to parse HTML with regex is a mug's game. It simply can't handle even the basic strucures of HTML, never mind the quirks. There's so much wrong with your snippet already. (Doesn't detect unquoted attributes; fails for a wide variety of punctuation in `it` due to lack of HTML-escaping, regex-escaping or CSS-escaping(*); failure for attributes with `-` in; strange non-use of `replace`...)

So, use the DOM. Yes, that'll mean a traversal. But then so does a selector like the `[attr*=]` you're using already.

```
var needle= 'foo';

$('*').each(function() {
    var tag= this.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if (tag==='script' || tag==='style' || tag==='textarea' || tag==='option') return;

    // Find text in attribute values
    //
    for (var attri= this.attributes.length; attri-->0;)
        if (this.attributes[attri].value.indexOf(needle)!==-1)
            $(this).addClass('ATTR');

    // Find text in child text nodes
    //
    for (var childi= this.childNodes.length; childi-->0;) {
        var child= this.childNodes[childi];
        if (child.nodeType!=3) continue;

        // Sole text content of parent: add class directly to parent
        //
        if (child.data==needle && element.childNodes.length===1) {
            $(this).addClass('TEXT');
            break;
        }

        // Else find index of each occurence in text, and wrap each in span
        //
        var parts= child.data.split(needle);
        for (var parti= parts.length; parti-->1;) {
            var span= document.createElement('span');
            span.className= 'TEXT';
            var ix= child.data.length-parts[parti].length;
            var trail= child.splitText(ix);
            span.appendChild(child.splitText(ix-needle.length));
            this.insertBefore(span, trail);
        }
    }
});
```

(The reverse-loops are necessary as this is a destructive iteration of content.)

(*: `escape` doesn't do any of those things. It's more like URL-encoding, but it's not really that either. It's almost always the wrong thing; avoid.)

Comment: it has been known to happen. ;-) (Well... adapted code from elsewhere, really.)

Comment: I actually forgot about escape. I meant escaping the string to be regex safe (since JS has no quote function), not the built-in escape *shudder*.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no good way to do this. Your last requirement makes you have to traverse the entire dom.

for the first 2 requirements i would select all elements by tag name, and interate over them inserting the stuff as needed.

only performance improvement i can think of is to do this on the server side at all costs, this may even mean an extra post to have your faster server do the work, otherwise this can be really slow on say, IE6